# Jenkins groovy init script for sonarqube configuration

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, sonarqube

I am trying to set sonarqube settings in Jenkins system property using groovy init script but I am getting below error. Can somebody help me to resolve this?

```
Error
+++++

groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: 
hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarInstallation(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, 
java.lang.String, hudson.plugins.sonar.model.TriggersConfig, 
java.lang.String)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1732)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1532)
```

This is the script that I am using

```
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarGlobalConfiguration
import hudson.plugins.sonar.*
import hudson.plugins.sonar.model.TriggersConfig
import hudson.tools.*

def inst = Jenkins.getInstance()

println "--> Configuring SonarQube"

SonarGlobalConfiguration global = Hudson.instance.getDescriptorByType(SonarGlobalConfiguration.class)

def sonar_inst = new SonarInstallation(
    "SonarQ",
    "http://localhost:9000",
    "yy", // Token
    new TriggersConfig(),
    ""
)

// Only add ADOP Sonar if it does not exist - do not overwrite existing config
def sonar_installations = sonar_conf.getInstallations()
def sonar_inst_exists = false
sonar_installations.each {
    installation = (SonarInstallation) it
    if (sonar_inst.getName() == installation.getName()) {
        sonar_inst_exists = true
        println("Found existing installation: " + installation.getName())
    }
}

if (!sonar_inst_exists) {
    sonar_installations += sonar_inst
    sonar_conf.setInstallations((SonarInstallation[]) sonar_installations)
    sonar_conf.save()
}
```

Comment: Can somebody help here to fix this?

Comment: [SonarInstallation](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-jenkins/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/sonar/SonarInstallation.java) constructor needs 7 parameters, not 5: `String name, String serverUrl, String serverAuthenticationToken, String mojoVersion, String additionalProperties, TriggersConfig triggers, String additionalAnalysisProperties)`

Comment: Thanks @agabrys. It worked like a charm. I understood I was missing few parameters but I did not know how many parameter is it accepting

Comment: Great. If this comment is a correct answer, then I will post it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed some parameters. [SonarInstallation](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-jenkins/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/sonar/SonarInstallation.java) constructor needs 7 parameters, not 5:

```
@DataBoundConstructor
public SonarInstallation(String name,
  String serverUrl, String serverAuthenticationToken,
  String mojoVersion, String additionalProperties, TriggersConfig triggers,
  String additionalAnalysisProperties) {
  this.name = name;
  this.serverUrl = serverUrl;
  this.serverAuthenticationToken = serverAuthenticationToken;
  this.additionalAnalysisProperties = additionalAnalysisProperties;
  this.mojoVersion = mojoVersion;
  this.additionalProperties = additionalProperties;
  this.triggers = triggers;
}
```